# Representing a C# Generic Method in a UML Class Diagram

Tags: c#, uml, generics, visio, class-diagram

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IRegisterable
{
   T Register<T>(string username, string passw) where T : User, ICanLogin, new();
}
```

`User` is an abstract class, and `ICanLogin` is another interface.

Now, I want to represent the above interface with its method in a UML Class Diagram, in Visio.

How can I represent the above generic method with its constraints in a Class Diagram ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML does not support type parametric methods directly.

About the closest you'll get is to define a nested class which has the type constraints with a stereotype which you will interpret as meaning it's a type parameter, and define the `Register` operation in terms of that.

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                   «interface»                     |
|                  IRegisterable                    |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| + Register (string username, string passw) : T    |
+---------------------------------------------------+

    +---------------+           +---------------+
    |  «abstract»   |           |  «interface»  |
    |     User      |           |   ICanLogin   |
    +---------------+           +---------------+
            .                           .
           /_\                         /_\
            |                           .
            +-----------+   .............
                        |   .
                +-------------------+              
                |  «typeParameter»  |
                | IRegisterable::T  |
                +-------------------+           
                | + new()           |
                +-------------------+           

    note: T is a nested class within IRegisterable
```

Answer (score 7):

A generic class is a Template class in UML 
see [What is the correct way to represent template classes with UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860501/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-template-classes-with-uml)

So can't you use thye Parameterized Class in Visio http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Parameterized+Class/

Answer (score 2):

UML **DOES** support parametric types (other things can be parametrized as well, and things other than types can be used as parameters as well).

Comment: Could you cite some "reliable source" for that? I'm just curious to learn more, especially about using "things other than types [...] as parameters as well".

Comment: For methods and Not classes?

Comment: See this blog post as "[Cliffs Notes](https://blog.abstratt.com/2007/11/01/uml-101-the-templates-package/)", the UML2 API javadoc (starting from [TemplateableElement](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/javadoc/5.0.0/org/eclipse/uml2/uml/TemplateableElement.html)), and search the [UML specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) for the strings TemplateableElement, TemplateSignature, TemplateParameter, ClassifierTemplateParameter, OperationTemplateParameter.