# Representing A Generic IList<T> in UML Notation

Tags: c#, uml

So, I have a method that returns a generic IList as follows: `public IList GetList();`. How you represent that in a UML class diagram?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080734/representing-a-c-generic-method-in-a-uml-class-diagram and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860501/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-template-classes-with-uml

Comment: I know how to represent classes, what I want to represent is the method IList<T> return type.

Answer (score 1):

In a UML diagram, a generic or template class would indicate that it aggregates type/class T.
Class AClass---aggregates---->T

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. It only shows the return type, and the reader must notice that this type is generic.

But what if you simply write IList as return type?

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080734/representing-a-c-generic-method-in-a-uml-class-diagram)

Comment: I was thinking on that... but then I saw an article that shows a class using template parameters to represent generic params.

Comment: I quickly found a post here, I added it on my post, maybe it will help.