# UML diagram for generic types?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, uml

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class A<U> {}
class B<T> : A <B<B<T>>> {}
```

How such types can be represented in UML class diagram?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080734/representing-a-c-sharp-generic-method-in-a-uml-class-diagram

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860501/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-template-classes-with-uml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure UML, I would use UML Template take a look at the section 17.4 of [UML2.4.1 specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/). You can also take a look at this thread dealing with [Java generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786771/uml-class-diagram-and-generics).
**But** if you want to generate C# code from your UML model, the UML specification would depend of the used tool and its generator...

For example under [Modelio](http://www.modelio.org/), `class A<U> {}` will be represented as

[image]

Comment: What about `class B<T> : A <B<B<T>>> {}`? Shall we define template inside template that refers to A?

Comment: Honestly I did not see how possible to model your example if your 'three B' are the same unique class...