# What Is the Difference Between semantic and concept?

Tags: uml, semantics, semantic-web, formal-semantics

i wonder what Is the Difference Between semantic and concept?
Is it possible a language shows concepts but not semantic?
Is is possible to modeling concept using syntax of language?
Dose UML Show conpet and semantic of system?
Thanks id advance

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're asking.  Can you provide an example?  To talk about "the semantics" of something is to talk about what that something "means", as opposed to what how that something is written or represented.  How you define the semantics of something depends on the context, but as a very simple example:  there's an `int` datatype in the C programming language.  Depending on the platform, compiler, machine, etc., the semantics of the `int` type may be "a 32-bit word", "a 64-bit word", etc.  In the sense that a UML diagram can be realized as code in lots of different…

Comment: …programming languages (or could be realized ways that don't have anything to do with programming languages), UML makes *concepts* explicit, but doesn't specify the semantics, aside from basic "types of resources" and some interactions that must be supported.  E.g., you could use UML to describe the responsibilities of employees in a company, or to describe some classes in a programming language.

Comment: For example if we about the object that have operation to add two number and retrun the result how much we can describe this object using UML?

Comment: what i think is that semantic is just set concepts and their relation am i wrong? so i think it should possible to show the semantic of object using uml.

Comment: You can define the interface that you would need for some arithemetic operations, sure.  You might be able to define some of the axioms that it ought to support (I'm not sure what constraints you can impose with UML) such as add(add(X,Y),Z) = add(X,add(Y,Z)) and add(X,Y) = add(Y,X).  But there can still be lots of different *implementations* of that interface.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24385863/2626313 and other [answers provided by @Cangnus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/715269/gangnus?tab=answers). You may find your philosophy-oriented answer already there or a hint. To me your question does not look like it fits on the Stack Overflow site, it should be rather moved to http://cs.stackexchange.com/ site as I don't see any direct value of your question for writing code - that is why you have my -1 vote

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that 'concept' is a noun and 'Semantic' is an adjective. The semantic part of a language construction is its concept.

Semantics (with 's' at the end) is a science about founding concepts/meanings.

An important detail in concept definition:

According to The Names Theory (the best text about it can be found in introduction part of the book of Alonso Church "the introduction to matemathical logics"), you should distinct concept from denotat:

Name "The recent king of France" has concept - it is a most important person, that rules a country in a monarchic way, now, and the country is France.
And it has no denotat, or the subject. Or you can say that the denotat is empty.