# Generic type constraints (where clause) in UML

Tags: c#, generics, uml, class-diagram, staruml

I have a generic C# class, which looks like this:

```
public class Database<T>
    where T : class, IModel, new()
{
    //Some code ...
}
```

T should implement the interface IModel and T have to be a class with an empty constructor.

The question is, how do this look in a UML class diagram.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representing a C# Generic Method in a UML Class Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080734/representing-a-c-sharp-generic-method-in-a-uml-class-diagram)

Answer (score 3):

### In short:

UML uses class templates for this purpose:

[image: UML class template with an ordinary class box, and a small doted box overlapping top right corner in which template paramters are shown]

For this to work,  you'd have to define somewhere (in a C# profile?) that [`NewConstraint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) is a special interface that requires the implementing class to have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, you could skip this the `NewConstraint` and add a simple UML constraint (e.g. a note with the constraint in plaintext `{ T shall have a parameterless constructor }` )

### Some more explanations about template parameters

More on the syntax of UML classifier template can be found in the UML specs (page 103):

> A *ClassifierTemplateParameter* extends the notation for a *TemplateParameter* to include an optional type constraint: 
> `<classifier-template-parameter> ::=` 
>      `<parameter-name> [ ‘:‘ <parameter-kind> ] [‘>’ <constraint>]`
>                        `[‘=’ <default>]`
> `<constraint> ::= [‘{contract }’] <classifier-name>*`
>
> The *parameter-kind* indicates the metaclass of the *parameteredElement*. **It may be suppressed if it is ‘Class.’**
>
> The *classifier-name* of constraint designates a `constrainingClassifier`, of which there may be zero or more, with the meaning specified in the semantics above. The ‘contract’ option indicates that *allowSubstitutable* is true.

Since I misunderstood the `{contract}` myself, and first confused it with an ordinary constraint, let's clarify this important hint:

- `{contract} xxx` means that the parameter allows the substitution of the parameter with a classifier having the same contract than `xxx`.  This is needed when a paramter is a class that is  constrained by specific interfaces.
- `xxx` (without `{contract}`) means that the parameter is required to be `xxx` or a specialization of it. In consequence, this cannot be used for a class that has to implement an interface, since the class is an implementation of an interface and not a specialization.

In your case, the parameter would then be:

```
T : class > {contract} IModel NewConstraint
```

But since class is the parameter-kind by default, it could be simplified to:

```
T > {contract} IModel NewConstraint
```