# How can I represent inheritance from a template parameter in UML?

Tags: c++, uml

Using UML, how can I represent `A< Foo >` in the following code?

```
template< class T > 
class A : public T
{
    /* ... */
};

class Foo { };

A< Foo > a_foo;
```

Something like this (apologies for the poor ascii art... and to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860501/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-template-classes-with-uml)) is my first guess, but I suspect it is not correct.

```
            ________________
            |              |
            |              |
            |     Foo      |
            |              |
            |______________|
             /:\  /|\
«bind»(Foo)   :    |
              :    |   .......               
            __:____|___:  T  :
            |          :.....:
            |              |
            |      A       |
            |              |
            |______________|
```

Comment: Doesn't the CRTP describe a class inheriting from a template class, where the inheritor passes itself as template parameter? In this case the generalization link should have the opposite direction. The bind dependency shown is correct IMHO.

Comment: @g-makulik - you're correct (as Luchiane pointed out below). I've modified the title.

Comment: @Luc Touraille - good title. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a proposal, by the U.M.L. designers, but, its not part of the standard, yet.

If, there wasn't any template parameters, the object "a" of type "A", may be like this:

```
+--------------------+
|        a: A        | 
+--------------------+
| [+] doSomething(); |
+--------------------+
```

The object "a", who is a template of "a", with the type parameter "Foo", may be represented like this:

```
                  +-----+
+-----------------| Foo |
|                 +-----+
|        a: A        | 
+--------------------+
| [+] doSomething(); |
+--------------------+
```

Note, that, in U.M.L., when you declare a class, they are represented by a rectangle, while specific objects, such "a", are represented by rectangle with round corners. Some people, & tools, doesn't follow the "round corners" specification.

Cheers.

Comment: So there is no standard way to represent this relationship today? 

Also, I'm curious, do you have a particular tool you like to use for UML? I'm using MS Visio right now and I'm by no means married to it.

Comment: @PaulH: No, I don't have a particular tool. I started with Rational Rose (UML Authors tools), Umbrello, & other tools, but, ended using Power Point, Visio & Libre Office Draw ( Open Source Version of Visio), because of limitations, not money or tools :-s

Comment: Personally I use the VisualParadigm Community (free and cross-platform) which is quite decent.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure if this is perfectly standard but this is the definition of your "A" class when I tried to reverse engineer it using Enterprise Architect:

```
      +---------+
+-----| T:class |
|     +---------+
|        T |
|   A      |
+----------+
|          |
+----------+
```

just add the name of the template parameter as the parent name of the class.