# UML diagram for the Curiously recurring template pattern

Tags: c++, uml

How do I correctly draw an UML diagram for the C++ Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) without replicating the base class for every inherited class, i.e. in a way that reflects the implementation rather than the situation after compilation?

The question boils down to:what do I write into the dashed box of the common template-baseclass if the template parameter can be any of a whole set of derived classes?

Comment: that doesn't answer my question; the case that the template parameter must be a derived class isn't mentioned at all.

Comment: I re-opened that since the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453540/how-can-i-represent-inheritance-from-a-template-parameter-in-uml was from 2012 (no idea which U.M.L. - lol  - version was out that time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the other answer an example of the C++ Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) is :

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
    // methods within Base can use template to access members of Derived
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

> what do I write into the dashed box of the common template-baseclass if the template parameter can be any of a whole set of derived classes?

The dashed box of the template class shows the template parameters, in case of the class Base :

[image]

The fact *the template parameter **can** be any of a whole set of derived classes* is not relevant because it can be anything else.

Adding the derived class in the diagram to have the full CRTP:

[image]

---

From your remark :

> that doesn't answer my question; the case that the template parameter must be a derived class isn't mentioned at all.

In your question you just say it **can** be, now you want it **must** be.

Note CRTP is defined by the *two* classes, not only by the base class. Anyway if you want to have that limitation concerning the template parameter (*T*) just use a constraint, may be *T.parents->includes(Base)* even I am not sure of the use of T in it, it must apply on the value(s) of *T* rather than *T* itself which is a class

[image]

---

From your remark to my answer :

> Another idea: would it be allowed to draw a collaboration connector from the base-classes T in the dashed box down to every depicted class that is derived from base?

I do not see how a collaboration can appear in that case, may be you think about a dependency ?

For me you cannot drawn relations from T in the dashed box, and even it is possible that does not indicate what you want.

Rather than to draw a relation from T to the derived classes just draw the derived classes with each time the inheritance and bind, that is the right way in UML.

[image]

Comment: my formulation "can be" may admittedly be interpreted in a way that doesn't exclude non-derived classes, but in the context of CRTP I think it is clear that only derived classes are to be considered as a template parameter; my apologiies for that..

Comment: Another idea: would it be allowed to draw a collaboration connector from the base-classes T in the dashed box down to every depicted class that is derived from base?

Comment: @user2961818 so yes you want *can*,  by definition without constraint all is possible including the fact you have the CRTP or not. I edited my answer to answer to your second remark

Comment: thank you very much for the updated diagram; that refects what I had hoped for.!