# How to model this C++ code using UML class diagram or SysML bdd?

Tags: uml, plantuml, sysml, sysml2

```
namespace collections {
  class Iterable : public Sized<T> 
  {}
}

class Item_id {}

class Item_info {}

class Connected_items : public collections::Iterable<std::map<Item_id, Item_info>>
{}
```

First, I like to see how this can be modeled as exact as possible.

Second, it would be nice to see how this can be simplified so the model is not cluttered with unnecessary details.

This is part of a large model. So having both inputs would be valuable.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to have it as exact as possible and do you want to adhere to some standard? Or is there something you want to bring across to other developers so that they understand what's going on? I would say: keep it as simple as possible and don't try to get all the private/public/inherits in, as long as the message is clear to others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for raising this question. First I like to see how this can be modeled as exact as possible. Then it would be nice to see how this can be simplified so the model is not cluttered with unnecessary details. This is part of a large model. So having both inputs would be valuable. Thanks. I am adding this to the question.

Comment: I think this C++ code doens't compile because of the missing semi-columns after each class definition ;-)

Comment: About simplifying the unnecessary details, especially standard template classes, you may look at this other answer that shows long and short versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73343908/3723423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would most likely go for something along these lines. It's written in mermaid, but PlantUML won't be much different. I couldn't get the `<>` working on the line of `T=map<Item_Id, Item_Info>`.

```
classDiagram

    class Item_Info
    class Item_Id
    class Connected_Items

    class Iterable~T~

    class Sized~T~

    Sized~T~ <|-- Iterable~T~
    Iterable~T~ <|-- Connected_Items : T=map{Item_Id, Item_Info}

    Connected_Items ..> Item_Info
    Connected_Items ..> Item_Id
```

[image: Image of the output]

And some other packages also support to put the T in the top right corner

[image]