# Hints to modelize several C++ templates patterns in UML

Tags: c++, uml, crtp

I use a lot templated classes in C++, and it is not easy to modelize them in UML.

How to modelize that, for example ?

```
template<template<typename> class TBaseId, class TFinalId>
class MyClass: public TBaseId<TFinalId>
{
};
```

Other point : is it possible to use ternary association instead of *bind* stereotype to modelize template associations ?

**Note** : I do know the basic template representation (with bind relationship). My needs are for more complex situations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to represent template classes with UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860501/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-template-classes-with-uml)

Comment: From that duplicate : https://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html